Keycloak clustering setup issue
I created a test virtual machine to apply Keycloak clustering.
I installed Keycloak version 26 there and set it up as follows.
conf/cache-ispn-tcpping.xml
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0">


    <jgroups>
        <stack name="tcpping" extends="tcp">
            <TCP bind_port="7805" bind_addr="10.0.0.5" external_addr="10.0.0.5" />
            <TCPPING
                initial_hosts="10.0.0.5[7805],10.0.0.6[7805]"
                port_range="0"
            />
            <FD_SOCK bind_port="57805"/>
            <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000"/>
            <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" max_bytes="50000"/>
            <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false" discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
            <UNICAST3 xmit_table_num_rows="1024" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"/>
            <MERGE3 min_interval="10000" max_interval="30000"/>
        </stack>
    </jgroups>



    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000" stack="tcp"/>
...

conf/keycloak.conf
...
cache=ispn
cluster=default
cache-stack=tcp
cache-config-file=cache-ispn-tcpping.xml
cache-remote-port=7805

However, when I run it, the following message is executed.

[root@vm-test keycloak-26.0.1]# ./bin/kc.sh start
2024-10-24 01:20:44,085 WARN  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli] (main) The following used run time options are UNAVAILABLE and will be ignored during build time:
        - cache-remote-port: Available only when remote host is set.
2024-10-24 01:20:47,021 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.infinispan.CacheManagerFactory] (main) Starting Infinispan embedded cache manager
2024-10-24 01:20:47,798 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (Thread-5) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
2024-10-24 01:20:48,263 WARN  [org.jgroups.stack.Configurator] (Thread-5) JGRP000014: ThreadPool.thread_dumps_threshold has been deprecated: ignored
2024-10-24 01:20:48,279 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (Thread-5) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `ISPN` with stack `tcp`
2024-10-24 01:20:48,280 INFO  [org.jgroups.JChannel] (Thread-5) local_addr: b2234e0f-3122-402a-9b7c-daea16717644, name: vm-test-20791
2024-10-24 01:20:48,301 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK2] (Thread-5) server listening on *.57800
2024-10-24 01:20:50,308 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (Thread-5) vm-test-20791: no members discovered after 2002 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
2024-10-24 01:20:50,318 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (Thread-5) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [vm-test-20791|0] (1) [vm-test-20791]
2024-10-24 01:20:50,396 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (Thread-5) ISPN000079: Channel `ISPN` local address is `vm-test-20791`, physical addresses are `[172.17.0.1:7800]`
2024-10-24 01:20:50,864 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: vm-test-20791, Site name: null
2024-10-24 01:20:50,872 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2024-10-24 01:20:52,061 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (main) Datasource '<default>': JDBC resources leaked: 7 ResultSet(s) and 0 Statement(s)
2024-10-24 01:20:52,378 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 26.0.1 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.15.1) started in 9.176s. Listening on: https://0.0.0.0:8443
2024-10-24 01:20:52,378 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2024-10-24 01:20:52,378 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-mssql, keycloak, narayana-jta, opentelemetry, reactive-routes, rest, rest-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]

I applied 7805 to the cache port that exists in all settings, but it operates as the default port 7800.
The IP also operates only as the internal docker IP 172.17.0.1:7800.
I can't find the cause at all.
How can I change the port number and the IP of the physical addresses???
